# Return Polymorphic class based on multiple variables

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I was hoping someone would help me on improving the efficiency of my code. I am currently improving my Java skills and unfortunately couldn't find any viable solutions.

The hypothetical scenario is:
I have a superclass Bird.

```
public class Bird {
    public Bird (Int Colour, String Size, Boolean Tropical, Boolean Migratory) {
       Int inColour = Colour; //[1 - Red, 2 - Blue, 3 - Yellow]
       String inSize = Size; //[S,M,L]
       Boolean inTrop = Tropical;
       Boolean inMig = Migratory;
       }
}
```

The following sub classes extend the superclass and have the  following specification:

Bird0 - Empty Bird, Place holder

BirdA - Colour: Red/Yellow | Size: S | Tropical: False | Migratory: False

BirdB - Colour: Red/Blue | Size: S | Tropical: True | Migratory: False

BirdC - Colour: Red/Blue| Size: M | Tropical: False | Migratory: True

BirdD - Colour: Blue/Yellow | Size: L | Tropical: True | Migratory: True

BirdE - Colour: Yellow/Blue | Size: M | Tropical: False | Migratory: True

The user selects the following attributes and then it is validated and passed into the superclass. The superclass has the following method to return the appropriate class.

```
public Bird selectBird(Int colour, String size, Boolean trop, Boolean mig ) {

    if (colour == 1 || colour == 3 && size = "S" && trop == False && Mig == False) {
        return new BirdA(colour, size, trop, mig);
    } else if (colour == 1 || colour == 2 && size = "S" && trop == True && Mig == False) {
        return new BirdB(colour, size, trop, mig);
    } else if (colour == 1 || colour == 2 && size = "M" && trop == False && Mig == False) {
        return new BirdC(colour, size, trop, mig);
    } else if (colour == 2 || colour == 3 && size = "L" && trop == True && Mig == True) {
        return new BirdD(colour, size, trop, mig);
   } else if (colour == 2 || colour == 3 && size = "M" && trop == False && Mig == True) {
        return new BirdE(colour, size, trop, mig);
   } else {
        return new Bird0();
   }
}
```

Based on the input passed into the superclass method. How would it be possible to select the appropriate subclass WITHOUT using IF statements. The Bird subclasses all have their individual properties to make them unique but share the attributes mentioned above. I read something about selecting classes using the Class Class in `java.lang` but still unable to find a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a List of possible Bird Implementation Classes, and have all your implementations register to it.

```
List<Class<? extends Bird>> birdClasses;
```

Now each class could define a static method canHandle(args), which you call by reflection

```
for( Class c : birdClasses ) {
    if( c.getMethod("canHandle").invoke(null, args) ) {
        return c.instantiate(args);
    }
}
return new Bird0(args)
```

Add exception handling and null checks. Also, for better style, you could create BirdFactory classes, so the canHandle method can be defined by an interface.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking to "improve efficiency," I will recommend that you change your hierarchy instead of answering the exact question you asked.

Get rid of all your subclasses, they are poorly formed. Instead, you should have methods in your `Bird` class called, for example, `isBirdA`, `isBirdB`, that return bools.

Then you just create a bird object, no if chain, or other magic, necessary, and your code will have a better structure.

Only subclass when there are differences in behavior, not just for differences in value.